# Is the standard implementation of Merge Sort preferable over an implementation written using vectors?

Tags: c++, sorting, mergesort, divide-and-conquer

I am learning Algorithms and was trying to come up with my own implementation of the Merge Sort. I wrote up the following implementation.

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

vector<int> merge(vector<int> A, vector<int> B)   
{
    int n1 = A.size();
    int n2 = B.size();
    vector<int> result;
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    while(i < n1 && j < n2)
    {
        if(A[i] < B[j])
        {
            result.push_back(A[i]);
            i++;
        }
        else
        {
            result.push_back(B[j]);
            j++;
        }
    }
    while(i<n1){
        result.push_back(A[i]);
        i++;
    }
    while(j<n2){
        result.push_back(B[j]);
        j++;
    }
    return result;
}   

vector<int> mergeSort(vector<int> M){
    int n = M.size();
    if (n==1){ return M; }
    else {
        vector<int> A;
        vector<int> B;
        int m = floor(n/2);
        for(int i = 0; i<m; i++){ A.push_back(M[i]);}
        for(int j =m;j<n; j++){ B.push_back(M[j]);}
        return merge(mergeSort(A), mergeSort(B));
    }
}

int main(){
    static const int arr1[] = {5332, 52, -41, 421, 54, 865, 987, 698430, -54670, -5436, 990}; 
    vector<int> A (arr1, arr1 + sizeof(arr1)/sizeof(arr1[0]));
    vector<int> C = mergeSort(A);
    for(vector<int>::const_iterator i = C.begin();i != C.end(); ++i){ cout << *i << " ";  }
    cout << "\n";
    return 0;   }
```

Then,when I went online to see the standard implementation of MergeSort, it was greatly different than mine. While they implementing the same concept, I was using vectors instead of C++ arrays and I didn't include array indices in the arguments.

What I'd like to ask is whether my implementation will be as good as the standard implementation, or should I just I just follow the standard implementation? I'm asking in terms of efficiency when the size of the input becomes a lot bigger.

Comment: Why not run a test? Time your implementation against the standard implementation and find out.

Comment: OK, so ran those tests against a 20-int long array, and I got the following results:
My method: 0.0004s
CLRS method: 0.0000s
I took the approximation to a thousand digits, but the CLRS method always get 0. I suppose that makes it better. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You're welcome. Although I can't really take any credit. You did all the work. =;)-
Please consider formalizing your results as an answer for any future visitors.

Comment: Testing should involve a much much larger data base. 20 items is nothing and the result is greatly influenced by the system state. I suggest to use datasets in the area of a million elements, also you should run the test several times and take the average value.

Comment: @NipunGarg, try running the tests on very large arrays, not a 20-int long array. With such small data sizes, a lot of irrelevant factors come into play.

Comment: If one is to compare the implementations, one needs to know the URL where you found the "standard" implementation.  But one place where the implementation might be optimized is to reuse existing memory on each call to `merge` rather than allocating new memory each time. Alternatively, it looks like you could improve your current implementation for large data sets by setting the capacity of `result` before you put any data in it, rather than letting the library increase the capacity as the size of the vector grows.

Comment: @Jan Thanks for the tip. I'll re-run the tests and share my findings.

Also, David Do you mean to say that I should set the size of the 'result' vector to 'n1+n2' when I call the merge function?